# using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text

Tags: google-app-engine

i am developing an application on Google app Engine i am saving HTML text in datastore using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text. All transaction working fine except for partial string which is stored in datastore. i don't the exact problem.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. Perhaps if you add some code that is failing this could be answered.

Answer (score 1):

The "java.lang.String"  that you would typically use is limited to 500 characters.

You need to import and use

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;
....


class HtmlItem {

     @Persistent
     private Text html;
}
```

Comment: yeah i8ts is certainly working but all the characters are not saved in data-store i have already tried this.

Comment: This is the only way you can do what the code is describing.  The code works... If there is a problem, it's not with this code.

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi  No, it does not explain how to get to the problem... This explains how to use the "Text" class to properly store large strings to GAE.